# Saving Results for each index of doparallel foreach

Tags: r, foreach

I am using a foreach loop and want to save the result for each index to access them later.
My code is more complicated than this but this is a sample code to explain my problem.

```
    w <- function(x){
    add = i+1
    multiply = i*2

    returned_values = list("add" = add, "mult" = multiply)
    }

    result <- foreach(i=1:length(new_data)) %dopar% w(i)
result$add
result$mult
```

Is there a way to store the results for all the indecies.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `foreach` will return the results as a list, each element corresponding to an iteration.

An easy way to achieve what you want is to store your intermediate results in an object (e.g. dataframe, list, ...) per iteration and then combine all results:

```
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)


cl <- makeCluster(parallel::detectCores())
registerDoParallel(cl)   #create a cluster



res <- foreach(i=1:10) %dopar% {

  data.frame(index=i,times2 = i*2)

}

stopCluster(cl)
```

This will give you the results list:

```
  res[1:2]
# [[1]]
# index times2
# 1     1      2
# 
# [[2]]
# index times2
# 1     2      4
```

You can combine the results now with `do.call`

```
do.call(rbind,res)
#    index times2
# 1      1      2
# 2      2      4
# 3      3      6
# 4      4      8
# 5      5     10
# 6      6     12
# 7      7     14
# 8      8     16
# 9      9     18
# 10    10     20
```

The same output can be achieved by adding `.combine = 'rbind'` as an argument to the `foreach` call.